# StyleCop.Analyzers in AspNetCore application and own rules set

Tags: asp.net-core, stylecop

How to enable own rules set for StyleCop.Analyzers in AspNetCore?
The analysis works but with a default set of rules.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a Project.json file:

```
"buildOptions": {
    "additionalArguments": [ "/ruleset:../../_shared/RULES.ruleset", "/additionalfile:../../_shared/stylecop.json" ]
}
```

See: https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/Configuration.md

Comment: This worked for me too. The documentation at the link you provided no longer mentions `"buildOptions"` in the `project.json` file. However if you add the line you mention the rules will be checked at build. Another thing to note is that the paths seem to be based on the location of the `project.json` file

Comment: @QueueHammer, thanks for giving the path of the relative location. They really should specify that.

Comment: Hi, looks like you got StyleCop.Analyzers to work with Asp.Net.Core. Can you please help me with: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40379981/enabling-stylecop-analyzers-on-asp-net-core-projects ?

Comment: Considering migration to new csproj format, what are the steps to include ruleset?

Comment: @xumix check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227639/supporting-roslyn-analyzers-ruleset-in-visual-studio-2017-net-core-projects/43227687#43227687

Comment: @SkorunkaFrantišek Thanks!