# Enabling StyleCop.Analyzers on ASP.NET Core projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, stylecop, project.json

According to the docs I've read online all you need to do is add the following to the dependencies in project.json:

```
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "DependencyA": "1.0.0-*",
    "DependencyB": "1.0.0-*",
    "StyleCop.Analyzers": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "build"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "net46": { }
  }
```

(where `DependencyA` and `DependencyB` are two .NET Core projects from the same solution)
and then StyleCop.Analyzers will run with the default rule set upon building the project. It doesn't. I get no warnings or anything and I'm pretty sure the code at the moment violates a lot of rules. Did anyone successfully get this working?

Comment: I'm not sure why it wouldn't be working for you -- I tried to reproduce it in my answer below and couldn't. Maybe post your whole `project.json`? There could be something that's conflicting with StyleCop.Anaylzers. Just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My .NET Core version was apparently too old. After upgrading to the latest one it now works.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working with Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 using the following steps:

1. Create a new project from the ASP.NET Core Application (.NET Core) template.
2. Add the `StyleCop.Analyzers` build dependency as you described in your question.
3. Build the project in Visual Studio and make sure the Error List output is set to **Build + IntelliSense**.

This is what I get:

[image: StyleCop warnings output]

I've confirmed that this also works for projects targeting `net451` instead of `netcoreapp1.0`, as well as Class Library projects targeting `netstandard1.X`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've edited the question with the actual file.