# Supporting Roslyn Analyzers(.ruleset) in Visual Studio 2017 .NET Core Projects

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, roslyn-code-analysis

How to add support for Roslyn Analyzers(.ruleset) in  Visual Studio 2017 .NET Core Projects?
In "project.json" it is configured by using `buildOptions`:

```
    "buildOptions": {
        "additionalArguments": [ "/ruleset:rules.ruleset" ]
    },
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just edit the .csproj file and add: 
`<PropertyGroup><CodeAnalysisRuleSet>rules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet></PropertyGroup>`

Note: path is relative to a .csproj file.

Original post here: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/supporting-roslyn-analyzers-visual-studio-2017-net-core-jake-brandt

Comment: This appears to only work for the StyleCop Analyzer, right? Have you found any way to get old Code Analysis (CAxxxx) rules to run in .NET Core projects.

Comment: Nevermind, it looks like you can just add `<RunCodeAnalysis>true</RunCodeAnalysis>` to make those rules work. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44726528/120955